# Alejar cámara en Unity + OVR (Oculus Vr) + Easy Movie Texture

Tags: c#, unity3d, vr

Buenas tardes. Les comento, prepare un reproductor 360 para GearVr, utilice el Easy Movie Texture para generar el video en dos esferas, y que la cámara del OVR tome una esfera con cada ojo. Ahora bien, comparado con el reproductor nativo de SamsungVr, el video se ve a una distancia, pero con el que prepare se ve muchisimo mas cerca (Todos los elementos estan ubicados en el (0,0,0)). Ahora bien, la pregunta es, como se puede regular la distancia de la cámara respecto al video que muestra la esfera?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puede que ajustar el Fov de la cámara te ayude a dar esa sensación de que esta mas lejos.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar varias cosas... O bien cambiar el Field Of View (FOV) de la camara, o bien cambiar el tamaño de las esferas (Cambiar el tamaño de las esferas no debería ser demasiado relevante a la hora de calcular la distancia a la que se ve el video pero podrías probar que efecto tiene en el resultado final)